# A question about two definitions of covering numbers

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, optimization, banach-spaces, approximation-theory

I am reading the book "Greedy approximation"(Page 208) written by V. Temlyakov and thinking about the following question of covering numbers:

Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $B_X(y,r)$ denote the ball of $X$ whose center is at $y$ with radius $r$.

Denote $N_{\epsilon}(A,X):=\min\{n: \exists  y^1, y^2, ... ,y^n, where\ \ each \ \ y^j\in X: A\subset \cup_{j=1}^n B_X(y^j,\epsilon)\}$.

Denote $N(A,\epsilon,X):=\min\{n: \exists  y^1, y^2, ... ,y^n, where\ \  each \ \   y^j\in A: A\subset \cup_{j=1}^n B_X(y^j,\epsilon)\}$.

Prove that:
$$N_{\epsilon}(A,X)\leq N(A,\epsilon,X)\leq N_{{\epsilon}/2}(A,X)$$

I can understand that the first inequality but I am a bit of confusion about the second inequality.

**My idea for the first inequality** is because for each $j$, $y^j\in A\subset X$. This means the minimum cover number would be smaller if we consider a bigger set. I have no idea why the second inequality is correct.

Any suggestions would be welcome and thank you !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Suppose $y^1, \ldots, y^n \in X$ such that the $B_X(y^j, \epsilon/2)$ cover $A$.
- Each ball contains some point of $A$ (else you can throw away that ball to get a smaller cover). Let these points be $z^1, \ldots, z^n$.
- Use the triangle inequality to argue that the balls $B_X(z^j, \epsilon)$ cover $A$.

Comment: Thank you! I can follow the first two steps. But for step 3, how to use the triangle inequality to show the balls with center $z^j\in A$ cover A as well?

Comment: @user431550 Any point of $A$ is near one of the $y^j$, and that $y^j$ is close to $z^j$.

Comment: So we first use the balls $\cup_{j=1}^n B_X(y^j, \epsilon/2)$ cover A. Then for each cover area, we can choose a point $z^j\in A \cap  B_X(y^j, \epsilon/2)$. Since for any $x\in A \cap  B_X(y^j, \epsilon/2)$, dist$(z_j, x )\leq \epsilon$. This means the ball  $  B_X(z^j, \epsilon)\supset  A \cap  B_X(y^j, \epsilon/2) $ and this implies  $\cup_{j=1}^n B_X(z^j, \epsilon)$ can cover A. Thus any $\epsilon/2$-cover from centers in $X$ generates a same number of $\epsilon$-cover with centers from $A$. This tells the covering number $N(A,\epsilon,X)$ would be smaller.  Does my understanding correct?

Comment: @user431550 Looks good to me